# EF 4.3 Migration - how to produce a downgrade script?

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-4.3, entity-framework-migrations

I have an issue which I could not find answer for across the web.

I am using CodeFirst EF 4.3.1 Migrations with MsSQL.

I have added several migrations and now I want to produce a script for upgrade/downgrade between two migrations.

For upgrade I run the following command which successfully reproduces an upgrade script:

```
PM> Update-Database -Script -SourceMigration:"201205161144187_AddPostAbstract" -TargetMigration:"201205161203310_BlogLimitsAndTableRename"
```

However, for downgrade I run the following command which fails with the following error:

```
PM> Update-Database -Script -SourceMigration:"201205161203310_BlogLimitsAndTableRename" -TargetMigration:"201205161144187_AddPostAbstract"
Scripting the downgrade between two specified migrations is not supported.
```

Any ideas how can I generate a downgrade script?

Thanks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It looks like migration API expects that you want to do downgrade only from "last version".

If `BlogLimitsAndTableRename` is your most recent migration (the last applied) you can simply run:

```
Update-Database -Script -TargetMigration:"201205161144187_AddPostAbstract"
```

If it is not your last migration you need to revert your development database to it first:

```
Update-Database -TargetMigration:"201205161203310_BlogLimitsAndTableRename"
```

and now you should be able to use the first command to get a script.

Comment: It makes kind of sense. Imagine you have database in state 5 and you'll try to get a script to downgrade from 4 to 3. Then the database can be easily corrupted. Either pointing it to db really in state 4 or having one locally pushed to state 4 makes you think about it before making irreversible mess. OTOH it could be supported with some -Force switch or big red warning. :)

Comment: I thought about having database in state 5 and now get a script to downgrade it from 5 to 2.
EF migration forces me to downgrade from 5 to 4, then to downgrade from 4 to 3 and then from 3 to 2, while all I wish is to produce a single script that will already contain all these downgrades without the need to really execute them. (For upgrade for example you can have a database in state 5 and produce a script of upgrade from 2 to 5).

Comment: Or you can have a database in state 5 and produce a script of upgrade from 2 to 4.

Comment: You can create downgrade script from current version (5) to version 2. You just need to run the first mentioned command with the name of the second migration.

Comment: For anybody using the `DbMigrator` and `MigratorScriptingDecorator` via c#, you oddly have to pass `sourceMigration: null` to the migrator's `ScriptUpdate` method.  Even if you pass the latest migration id, it still complains that you can't downgrade between two versions (same error as OP)